# Display Top Content in Woocommerce categories above products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, move

Using Flatsome + Woocommerce.

In product Categories, I would like to display
"Top Content": Above products.
And also "Description": Below Products.

Found some answers to move "Description" below products

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );
```

but none related to the "Top Content" above the products.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Top content above products]

Comment: Hello, I see that you are new. You say that you have already found some answers to move "Description" below products, can you share that code here by editing your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @L7c1f3r To move "Description" below products:
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 ); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );

Comment: I don't use the flatsome theme, do you have a URL to your website? or an url to a demo website of your used theme (variant)? it is not entirely clear to me where 'top content' is located

Comment: Hi, you can check it here: https://cutt.ly/WrMYrpH

Comment: It seems that that text is somehow under </header> and before <div class = "shop-page" .. (see attached image https://pasteboard.co/IVrckuk.jpg ) I therefore think that you can only delete this in one of your theme files but cannot move it with a hook. 
Is there a setting somewhere in your theme that you can use to change that text?